# Not slap happy. Is it an emotion or action?

Tags: meaning

What is the term for when you smack someone because you're so happy?

Comment: roughhousing? horseplay? rollicking? rough-and-tumble?

Comment: . . . Drunk? . . .

Comment: ...assault and battery?

Comment: People stereotypically slap their own thigh when they're happy or laughing. Not sure about this though.